# Tuple Index out of Range PIL when using Image.fromarray()

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library

I am trying to process some CIFAR10 image data into image tiles for plotting with PIL on a black canvas. I have had success doing this while extracting features from a trained model but I keep getting `IndexError: Tuple Index out of range` when using Image.fromarray.

My features are shaped to be test data of shape (10000,3072). The data is 32x32x3 images.
I load cifar10 data and then flatten the data but keep getting this error.

Here is my code. Some of it is borrowed from https://medium.com/@pslinge144/representation-learning-cifar-10-23b0d9833c40

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from time import time
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
from time import time
from keras.datasets import cifar10

# Load the raw CIFAR-10 data
_, (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

# normalize the xtest data
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_test /= 255.0

features = X_test # this is (10000, 32, 32, 3) numpy array
features = np.reshape(features, (10000, 3072)) # flatten to 2d array
print(features.shape)

perplexities = [5, 30, 50, 100]
for perplexity in perplexities:
    print("Starting t-SNE on images now!")
    tsne = TSNE(n_components = 2, init = 'random', random_state = 0, perplexity = perplexity, learning_rate = 200).fit_transform(features)

    tx, ty = tsne[:,0], tsne[:,1] # grab tsne first and 2nd dimensions
    # min max normalize for plotting
    tx = (tx-np.min(tx)) / (np.max(tx) - np.min(tx))
    ty = (ty-np.min(ty)) / (np.max(ty) - np.min(ty))
    width = 4000
    height = 3000
    max_dim = 100
    full_image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    for idx, x in enumerate(features):
        tile = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x * 255), 'RGB') # rescale pixel values to [0,255] scale
        rs = max(1, tile.width / max_dim, tile.height / max_dim)
        tile = tile.resize((int(tile.width / rs),int(tile.height / rs)),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        full_image.paste(tile, (int((width-max_dim) * tx[idx]),int((height-max_dim) * ty[idx])))

        plots_output_path = Path('../data/processed/tSNE_plots').resolve()
        filename = "tsne_perplex%d_plot.png" % (perplexity)
        fullpath = plots_output_path.joinpath(filename).resolve()
        full_image.save(str(fullpath))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tSNE_image_thumbnail.py", line 80, in <module>
    tSNE_image(x_test, 1000, 200, plots_output_path, 2)
  File "tSNE_image_thumbnail.py", line 56, in tSNE_image
    tile = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x * 255), 'RGB')
  File "/home/zw/src/image_classification_ML/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2728, in fromarray
    size = shape[1], shape[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Again, this code works fine when extracting my features from my CNN model and using it on a shape (10000, 512) dense layer. Not sure why this is giving me issues. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you print `x` just above `tile = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x * 255), 'RGB')` ? `np.uint8(x * 255)` might render a scalar if `x` is a scalar...

Answer (score 1):

Your are providing arrays with the length of '3072' in your line

```
tile = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x * 255), 'RGB')
```

Simply verify it by calling `np.uint8(x * 255).shape` for an x, which returns `(3072,)`.

But for an 'RGB' image, you need a dimensionality of 3, not just 1.

Because of that, you get the error `tuple index out of range`, since an array with three entries and not just one is expected.

That means instead of your (3072,) you need a tuple with three entries, so for example (8,96,4), which would map your one-dimensional array of 3072 values to a matrix of `8 x 96 x 4` (=3072) values.

So you could change the line in your code to

```
tile = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x).reshape(8,96,4),'RGB')
```

But at the end, you should define the shape according to the image dimensions.